# Sniff UDP packets on a local port

Tags: networking

I'd like to know what are the contents of a packet one application "APM Planner" send to another "MAVProxy". I know they are communicating over UDP port 14550. I tried using **tcpdump** by running the following commands

```
tcpdump -u port 14550
```

and

```
tcpdump udp
```

and

```
netstat -uanpc | grep 14550
```

but none of them displayed me what these two applications are really exchange. I need something like **cutecom** for monitoring the UDP connection. Is there anything like this?
When I run the command

```
netstat -lnpuc
```

, it shows the following among its output

```
udp 5376 0 0.0.0.0:14550 0.0.0.0:* 23598/apmplanner2
```

Comment: Have you considered the GUI program called `wireshark`?  It'll dissect the packets and show you the information being sent by each, and you can then use `udp.port == 14550` or similar as the filtering command to only show that traffic.  The problem is, you'll have to piece together what's going back and forth based on the contents of the packet.  But it sounds like this is ultimately what you want to do yourself... (Just sniff the `lo` interface if you do this - that's the 'local' 127.*.*.* range and local IPv6 internally on your system)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I installed Wireshark and typed `udp.port == 14550` in `Apply a display filter` filed but nothing appeared. I also tried `udp port 14550` in the `Enter a capture filter` field. Also when I run the command `netstat -lnpuc`, it shows the following among its output `udp     5376      0 0.0.0.0:14550           0.0.0.0:*                           23598/apmplanner2
`

Comment: Sounds to me like it's not necessarily listening locally.  have you tried tracing on other interfaces to see if it's communicating outbound?

Comment: Now it's working. I had to run `wireshark` with `sudo`.  Many thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**tcpdump** supports *UDP capturing*. example usage:

```
tcpdump -n udp port 14550
```

## Edit

Because your applications are communicating with **lo** interface you must specify interface like this:

```
tcpdump -i lo -n udp port 14550
```

this command print headers only. if you want to print data part of packet in hex and ASCII use this:

```
tcpdump -i lo -n udp port 14550 -X
```

or if you want to save packets to a file and see it's content in **Wireshark** use this:

```
tcpdump -i lo -n udp port 14550 -w packets.pcap
```

Comment: I tried this command but it doesn't capture the packets. It outputs the following `listening on wlo1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes` and nothing else!

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf I fixed it :)

Comment: thanks, it's working now. It displays source, destination and length of transferred data. Is it possible to make it display the transfered data itself?

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf yes. you must append option `-A`  to tcpdump to see data. also you can send packet to a file and see packets in **Wireshark** by `-w packets.pcap`

Comment: Pahlvan, Great. Now I can see the data. Is it possible to make the data displayed in hex? Many thanks

Comment: @SalahuddinAshraf `-X` show you both **hex** and **ASCII** :)

Comment: does this show anything if another process is already reading the packets?

Comment: yes, tcpdump captures a copy of all packets from network interface

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[ngrep](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ngrep)**. Example:

```
# Any UDP from any local interfaces to 91.22.38.4:12201
ngrep -W byline -d any udp and host 91.22.38.4 and dst port 12201
```